# Why do I get the same "updates available" for apps even though I have already updated that app before on my S3?

Tags: google-play-store, notifications

I have noticed that my Google Play apps keep notifying me of apps with new updates but when I click on it I see that's it's sometimes an app a old update which I have already installed but the "update" button is still there for apps which I have definitely updated. What is the fix and the cause?

OS: 4.1
S3

Comment: When you say "notifying me" do you mean an Android notification at the top of the screen (where missed call/new email icons go)? Or do you mean the apps are listed in the Play Store as being new? There was a recent change to the play store and now it shows a list of the apps you've updated on your phone from the last 3 (I believe) days, headed 'recently updated'.

Comment: Just because the description hasn't changed doesn't necessarily mean they haven't updated the app.  Some devs are lazy about that.

Comment: I mean in the status bar when it says "new updates available" for so and so apps.  @Compro02l1: I know for fact that an app that said "new update" was not new because I had emailed the dev and the last updated date on their Google Play page had not changed.

Comment: I thought this was the case for Skype, but it turns out they aren't updating the version number in their description. If I check Skype under Settings/Apps, then the version number does increase.